# The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow, appdelegate

I'm programmatically implement a list view controller.
When I try to run the project, I got error:

```
2012-11-07 22:46:34.719 myTableViewControl[12021:c07] The app delegate must implement the         window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.
2012-11-07 22:46:34.722 myTableViewControl[12021:c07] -[AppDelegate setWindow:]:     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7674e70
2012-11-07 22:46:34.723 myTableViewControl[12021:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setWindow:]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x7674e70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c8e012 0x10cbe7e 0x1d194bd 0x10df7ea 0x1c7dcf9 0x1c7d94e 0x1d60 0x107b7 0x10da7     0x11fab 0x23315 0x2424b 0x15cf8 0x1be9df9 0x1be9ad0 0x1c03bf5 0x1c03962 0x1c34bb6 0x1c33f44     0x1c33e1b 0x117da 0x1365c 0x1bd2 0x1b05)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

When I run the code, it hang on the main.m and shows that

> "thread1: signal SIGABRT"

```
@autoreleasepool {return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

my code is as following:
AppDelegate.h

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  myTableViewControl
//
//  Created by Max on 12-11-5.
//  Copyright (c) 2012年 Max. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  myTableViewControl
//
//  Created by Max on 12-11-5.
//  Copyright (c) 2012年 Max. All rights reserved.
//

    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "firstViewController.h"


@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize navigationController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // create the base window
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.window = window;

    [window release];

    // this is the home page from the user's perspective

    FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:fvc];
    self.navigationController = nc;

    [fvc release];
    [nc release];

    // show them
    [self.window addSubview: nc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

FirstViewController is list view controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441682/the-app-delegate-must-implement-the-window-property-if-it-wants-to-use-a-main-st)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are creating your window as a local variable and then trying to access it as if it were a property by using `self.window`.  Make it a property.

Comment: Phillip is correct. You are missing this line from the header file:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;`

Comment: Also, when you already have that `@property` and it still throws a runtime error, have a look whether you have also `@synthesize` for it.  It somehow miraculously **works without it** for XCode 4.5 and iPhone 5. I haven't tried any other combination, because i found this error beforehand.

Comment: @PavelZdenek Yes, this is due to the new objective-C 2.0 feature, automatic synthesizing of properties.