# Specify App Delegate for Storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, appdelegate

I'm trying to change my App's main interface which currently is set to a .xib file in the project's "General Configuration Pane" to a new storyboard.

I have created the storyboard, and selected it as the main interface.
But when I launch the application in simulator, I get a black screen and the following message printed in the console : "There is no app delegate set. An app delegate class must be specified to use a main storyboard file."

How should I do that ?

Comment: did you set mainWindow

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly, but I didn't specifically set anything about main window !

Comment: post your code or link your sample project

Comment: Seeing your comment suggestion to attention to the "window", I searched about setting the window a bit, and this solved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272346/the-app-delegate-must-implement-the-window-property-if-it-wants-to-use-a-main-st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you set mainWindow if you are not please set your window in your project

Comment: how? where? which panel?

Answer (score 5):

The app delegate class is generally specified in main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([TCAppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method put these code lines .

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard; = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
      [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];

return Yes ;
```

Comment: The problem was that there were no self.window property

Comment: Then you can simply declare a property ( @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window; ) in your AppDelegate.h file